# Linux grep, how can I display lines that don't contain word 1 and word 2 but still display the lines that have both words in them

Tags: linux, grep

I need some help with displaying all lines that don't contain `word1` or `word2` but lines that contain both of them have to be shown.

Example:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
bbbb bbbb bbbb
cccc cccc cccc
dddd dddd aaaa
```

if `word1 = aaaa` and `word2 = bbbb` then output should be:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
cccc cccc cccc
```

Tried

```
grep -Ewv "word1/word2" file.txt
```

but this shows only lines that don't contain them, it doesn't show lines containing both

I need to do this with grep command, forgot to mention this

Comment: Did you make some progress towards this?  Post your attempts even if they failed

Comment: grep -Ewv "word1/word2" file.txt but this shows only lines that don't contain them, it doesn't show lines containing both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep version of both or none of each:

```
grep -v -P '((?=.*aaaa)(?!.*bbbb))|((?=.*bbbb)(?!.*aaaa))'
```

But please do not use `grep` in this case. [Negative and positive look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can easily lead to [Catastrophic Backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

GNU `grep` knows Perl compatible regular expression (PCRE) syntax (option `-P`). This thing is still called a "regular" expression, although it not regular anymore. Other people are more explicit and call backtracking [irregular](http://synthcode.com/scheme/irregex) expressions.

How it works:

`(?=.*aaaa)` matches `aaaa` anywhere in the line, but does not move the cursor. After the match the next search starts at the beginning of the line.

`(?!.*bbbb)` matches when no `bbbb` is in the line and does not move the cursor either.

Both together matches lines, which include `aaaa` but do not include `bbbb`.

This is one of the cases you want to exclude, from your search results. The second behind the or condition (`|`) is the other one you want to exclude: any `bbbb` without a `aaaa`.

With the above, you have defined, what you do not want. Next use `-v` to invert the search to get what you want.

[image: intended output]

Comment: I don't understand. (To be honest: I believe this answer is 100% wrong, despite the OP's careless marking of it as "correct".) Simple testing shows it's wrong. Now **why** it is wrong: the negative assertion simply looks for a position where the negatively asserted word is not present. That will match many positions in the input string. So let's say the words are `aaaa` and `bbbb` and we are looking at the string `aaaa bbbb`. This will match the search pattern: the negative assertion will match **after** the first 'b'. Right? I don't see how this approach can be made to work.

Comment: To be clear - what I mean is that lines where both words are present will not be filtered out.

Comment: @mathguy You do not need to believe, just try it.

Answer (score 0):

Bash version of both or none of each:

```
#! /bin/bash

word1=${1:-aaaa}
word2=${2:-bbbb}

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $word1 ]]; then
    if [[ $line =~ $word2 ]]; then
      printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
  else
    if [[ $line =~ $word2 ]]; then
      :
    else
      printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help me, I need to learn how to use Linux commands. I have to do this with grep, thx for the effort though :D

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest way (even though possibly not the fastest) is to find separately the lines that contain neither word and the lines that contain both words, and to concatenate the results. For example (assuming `file.txt` is a text file in directory `test`, and I pass the input values as environment variables for generality - and we are only looking for full words, not word fragments):

```
[mathguy@localhost test]$ more file.txt
aaaa bbbb cccc
bbbb bbbb bbbb
cccc cccc cccc
dddd dddd aaaa



[mathguy@localhost test]$ word1=aaaa
[mathguy@localhost test]$ word2=bbbb

[mathguy@localhost test]$ ( grep "\b$word1\b" file.txt | grep "\b$word2\b" ; \
>  grep -v "\b$word1\b" file.txt | grep -v "\b$word2\b" ) | cat
aaaa bbbb cccc
cccc cccc cccc
```